# How to decrypt a file into a string using OpenSSL inside Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I'm new to programming and I'm using OpenSSL inside a Rails app to decrypt the content of a file into another file.

`openssl enc -in "#{bin}" -a -A -out "#{stamp}"`

But I need the result of the decryption into a variable (string) and not into a file. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes and you don't need to use the shell command. Ruby has a wrapper for the OpenSSL library built in. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html

Comment: If you REALLY wanted to use the shell command you could use `my_var = \`openssl enc -in "#{bin}" -a -A\``. If you remove the `-out` option OpenSSL will print the ouput. Backticks run the shell command and return its output.

Comment: But beware of the potential remote execution vulnerability if `bin` originates from an untrusted source.